# Error when accessing a resource: "param is missing or the value is empty: article"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to pass in the whole object to my show action in order to update its `viewed` field, but for some reason I keep getting this error.

[image]

Why is that?

**index.html.erb**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
```

**controller**

```
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.viewed += 1
    @article.update(article_params)
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit!
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you have the following line

```
params.require(:article).permit!
```

The `require` method invocation will raise the error you are experiencing if the `params` hash doesn't contain an `article` hash.

As you can see from the error page, your current parameters are

```
{"id"=>"1"}
```

There is no `article` hash. That's the issue.

Checking your code even further, the following line doesn't make sense at all

```
@article.update(article_params)
```

You pretend to update the `@article` from some parameters in the `show` action. However, you have at least two issues here:

1. The parameters are not passed in any way
2. That's a `show` action and it is not supposed to update a resource

It's likely to me you just want to increment the counter. If that's the case, your action should be

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.viewed += 1
  @article.save!
end
```

or even better you can use [`increment!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21)

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.increment! :viewed
end
```

Comment: And is that record going to be saved without Active Record's save or update methods?

Comment: You can easily find the confirmation in the docs for [`increment!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-increment-21)